# looking for a Job Notification when Job fails only five time in 10 minutes

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Is it possible to configure a Notification Alert rule for SQL Jobs that notify only when fails X times? I have a SQL Job that executes each X Second and causes too many emails, I think if we can trigger alerts only if there have been 5 failures in 10 minutes.

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking into *why* it's failing so frequently..

Comment: Not natively through SQL Agent.  For a pure SQL Server solution you'd have to create that logic yourself.  Maybe create a stored procedure to check the job failures through msdb or something similar.  In which case you'd need to remove the existing notification and send notifications through sp_send_dbmail.  You could then have that proc run at the end of your existing job.

Comment: But yeah, what @Larnu said, too.  Getting that many notifications would certainly drive me to correct the failure issue...

Comment: Maybe look at a proper monitoring solution such as SQLMonitor from Redgate which can be configured to raise alerts on various job failure conditions.

Comment: @squillman, as I am new to SQL and still  learning SQL, Can you please help me with the Stored Procedure structure so I can edit it accordingly.

Comment: @user14487969 That's really better posted as a new question, but you'll want to put something together yourself first and then post a specific question about what you get stuck with.  To get started, you can query job history with this: `SELECT j.name, js.step_name, h.*
FROM dbo.sysjobs j INNER JOIN dbo.sysjobsteps js ON js.job_id = j.job_id INNER JOIN dbo.sysjobhistory h ON h.job_id = j.job_id AND h.step_id = js.step_id WHERE h.run_status = 0;`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.